# Hyperlinks in contextMenues (wpf, partial trust) didn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, hyperlink

I got a problem. I have a contextmenu and it's items are hyperlinks.
If I click on those nothing happened.
They are OK, because if I add them to a grid they work fine.

Anybody an idea how to solve this?
I am in an partialTrust environment ... so Process.start is not running.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution ... so simple ...

just wrap a frame around the link ...